# How to expand following XML into a table in TSQL?

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am not very familiar with XML in SQL server. I need to expand the following XML to a table, but I don't know how to do that. Can someone help me?

```
<MainNode>
    <Type>Type1</Type>
    <Group>Group1</Group>
    <IDFile>File1</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File2</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File3</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File4</IDFile>
    <XP>XP1</XP>
    <SubNode>
        <Data1>Data1</Data1>
        <Data2>Data2</Data2>
    </SubNode>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>PName1</Name>
            <Value>PVal1</Value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>PName2</Name>
            <Value>PVal2</Value>
          </Parameter>
    </Parameters>         
</MainNode>
```

My main issue is how to expand sub nodes which contain more than one element. I also have repeating nodes with unknown number.

I use `.nodes()` and `.value()` functions

My code looks like:

```
declare @XML xml = '<MainNode>
    <Type>Type1</Type>
    <Group>Group1</Group>
    <IDFile>File1</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File2</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File3</IDFile>
    <IDFile>File4</IDFile>
    <XP>XP1</XP>
    <SubNode>
        <Data1>Data1</Data1>
        <Data2>Data2</Data2>
    </SubNode>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>PName1</Name>
            <Value>PVal1</Value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>PName2</Name>
            <Value>PVal2</Value>
          </Parameter>
    </Parameters>         
</MainNode>';

SELECT 
    Child.value('(Type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Type], 
    Child.value('(Group)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS [Group] 
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/MainNode') AS N(Child);
```

I need something like:

```
Type1 | Group1 | XP1 | Param1.1 Name | Param1.1 Value
Type1 | Group1 | XP1 | Param1.2 Name | Param1.2 Value
Type2 | Group2 | XP2 | Param2.1 Name | Param2.1 Value
```

...

Comment: What would your final desired SQL Table look like when populated with the example XML data you provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... There are many different data structures within your XML... It doesn't make much sense, to retrieve all of them in one query.

In the following code I show you, how you might get something out of it. I hope you get enough templates, to manage the rest on your own.

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<MainNode>
  <Type>Type1</Type>
  <Group>Group1</Group>
  <IDFile>File1</IDFile>
  <IDFile>File2</IDFile>
  <IDFile>File3</IDFile>
  <IDFile>File4</IDFile>
  <XP>XP1</XP>
  <SubNode>
    <Data1>Data1</Data1>
    <Data2>Data2</Data2>
  </SubNode>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter>
      <Name>PName1</Name>
      <Value>PVal1</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Name>PName2</Name>
      <Value>PVal2</Value>
    </Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</MainNode>';
```

--The `XQuery` predicate will read all nodes with the name "IDFile" below `<MainNode>`:

```
SELECT 
    idf.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS IDFile
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/MainNode/*[local-name()="IDFile"]') AS N(idf);
```

--Key-Value-Pairs: Within `<MainNode><SubNode>` there are KVPs:

```
SELECT 
    SubNode.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS NodeName, 
    SubNode.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS NodeValue
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/MainNode/SubNode/*') AS N(SubNode);
```

--Within `<MainNode/Parameters>` there is a typical `1:n`-related sub-structure:

```
SELECT 
    Prm.value('Name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS ParamterName, 
    Prm.value('Value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS ParameterValue
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/MainNode/Parameters/Parameter') AS N(Prm);
```

Comment: Just what I need, 10x @Shnugo